# Grant a role permission to View custom links without granting permission to View all content

Tags: security, permissions, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

**Use Case**

We want to allow the anonymous role to view both **Pages** and **Custom Links** to them. We have another content type, called **Secure Page**, that we do not want the anonymous role to view.

**Implementation**

In order to restrict the anonymous role from viewing **Secure Pages**, we did not grant it permission to view all content. Then we granted it permission to view **Pages**. The problem is, that we cannot grant it permission to view **Custom Links**. Without having the view all content permission, anonymous cannot view **Custom Links**.

**Question**

Can we grant a role permission to view **Custom Links** without also granting permission to view all content?

**More Details**

If we do not grant view all content to a role, in the navigation, that role can only view **Content Menu Items** that link to the Content Types it can view. This is good! In our case, anonymous can view **Content Menu Items** that link to **Pages** but not that link to **Secure Pages**. Fantastic.

The problem is that the role cannot view any other menu item type. It cannot view the **Html Menu Item** nor the **Custom Link** - it can only view specific **Content Menu Items.**

This is problematic. We need to let anonymous view **Custom Links.**